# Expanding tilde inside assignments and strings in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Inspired by the work Charles Duffy did in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29310360/258523) and the work of Jonathan Leffler in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15859646/258523) and because I couldn't leave well-enough alone.

I went and wrote [expandTilde.sh](https://github.com/deryni/expandTilde.sh):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

doExpand() {
  local path
  local -a resultPathElements

  for path in "$@"; do
    : "$path"
    case $path in
      "~+")
        path=$PWD
        ;;
      "~+"/*)
        path=$PWD/${path#"~+/"}
        ;;
      "~-")
        path=$OLDPWD
        ;;
      "~-"/*)
        path=$OLDPWD/${path#"~-/"}
        ;;
      "~")
        path=${HOME-~}
        ;;
      "~"/*)
        path=$HOME/${path#"~/"}
        ;;
      "~"[0-9]|"~"[+-][0-9])
        local num=${path#"~"}
        local op=${num%%[0-9]*}
        num=${num#[+-]}
        local opath=$path
        if [ "$op" = "-" ]; then
          ((num+=1))
        fi
        path=${DIRSTACK[@]: $op$num:1}
        : "${path:=$opath}"
        ;;
      "~"*)
        local username=${path%%/*}
        username=${username#"~"}
        IFS=: read -r _ _ _ _ _ homedir _ < <(getent passwd "$username")
        if [ "$homedir" ]; then
            if [[ $path = */* ]]; then
              path=${homedir}/${path#*/}
            else
              path=$homedir
            fi
        fi
        ;;
    esac
    resultPathElements+=( "$path" )
  done
  local result
  printf -v result '%s:' "${resultPathElements[@]}"
  printf '%s\n' "${result%:}"
}

expandAssign() {
  local -a pathElements
  IFS=: read -r -a pathElements <<<"$1"
  : "${pathElements[@]}"
  doExpand "${pathElements[@]}"
}

expandString() {
    doExpand "$1"
}
```

So two questions:

1. Did I miss any cases or get any cases wrong? (Tests in the github repo.)
2. Can this be improved in any meaningful ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` is most useful when its order of expansion is considered. if you construct your conditions in such a way that a previous match will narrow the possibilities for the current match, then you can get much nearer much quicker to your target match. what's more, `case` seems always to make better sense as a function in itself - so that it might call itself recursively when matches are ambiguous. consider the following:

```
   pathcase()
        case    $1 in  ([!~]*|'') ! :;;       ### ^tilde or else
        (*/*)
            pathcase "${1%%/*}" "${1#*/}"     ### squeeze to relevant ele
        ;;
        (?)
            path=${HOME-~}${2+/$2}            ### let expansions work, to
        ;;
        (?-)
            path=${OLDPWD:+$OLDPWD${2+/$2}}   ### its not always set
        ;;
        (?+)
            path=$PWD${2+/$2}                 ### it should be
        ;;
        (?*[!-+0-9]*|??*[-+]*)                ### negate
            pathchk -p -- "${1#?}" &&         ### requires standards comp
            eval '[ "$1" != '"$1 ] &&         ### which makes this safe
                  path=$1${2+/\$2}"           ### and this
        ;;
        (${BASH_VERSION+$(( path  =
         ${#DIRSTACK[@]}-${1#?+}-1))}|\
         ${BASH_VERSION+${path##-*}}*)        ### matches !bash||bad inde
            unset path
           ${path?bad tilde: "$1${2+/$2}"}    ### break w/ error
        ;;
        (?+*)
            path=${DIRSTACK[${1#?+}]}${2+/$2}
        ;;
        (*) path=${DIRSTACK[path]}${2+/$2}
        esac
```

Comment: Nice. This is certainly much shorter. The recursion is clever (though I don't know how much it really helps here). This doesn't quite work correctly though (it fails on the `~+` non-digit, the `~-` digit cases and the `~+` digit out of bounds cases). Fixing the latter is easy (just check for that before indexing into `DIRSTACK`). Fixing the others is escaping me at the moment. Also indexing into `DIRSTACK` generates a warning that mine doesn't. I've made some changes to mine based on insights from this though. You can check the repo for them (the new version is only 25 lines for the case).

Comment: @EtanReisner - what's it supposed to do with a non-digit? the recursion matters - but it only ever happens the one time, of course. it makes it *much* easier to negate. I was able to use the dirstack thing. in truth, i almost never use `bash` - or arrays - and i'm admittedly not all that hip to the popdirs deals, but i checked and it worked for `$PWD` and `$OLDPWD` and a stack of 4 or 5 test dirs.

Comment: @EtanReisner - i guess i know what you mean now about the negatives failing now - apparently `bash` reports errors for unset array indexes only when  they are referenced in reverse - with a the - negative index. so i fixed that by doing less and just `~` twiddling the negative indexes. but how do the positives fail? if a user references an unset index `$path` should be set null - or else `unset` altogether. that would make sense, but what else should happen?

Comment: Ah... I see what the recursion gains you now. Yeah, that is useful. I would probably have just handled that manually myself. This version still fails on a number of tests (and this shouldn't error on a bad tilde it should just return the original, which assigning in the case label, while clever, makes a bit hard without adding a temporary variable). I think I'll be accepting this answer though as it gave me many insights, a few new test cases and caused great improvements to the original.

Comment: I might file a new question with the current code to get more feedback though. (... Eventually at least given the pace at which I got answer to this question. =))

Comment: @EtanReisner - i think thats a philosophical difference then - i prefer it when my tools error with a meaningful message - when this fails it fails with line number, bad values, $0, and kills a scripted shell. that's how *all* of my tools behave - i dont like silent failure. it does all of that in any posix shell, by the way. if i were to use it as part of another tool, i would just validate its input - in the same way i do with any other tool.

Comment: I don't entirely disagree with the philosophy that it should fail or with the way you did it. That's just not how bash actually works. POSIX itself only specifies the login name expansion and leaves a number of cases unspecified (so erroring would be perfectly valid).